# Adding disableLogs: true will return 'An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - Policy statement must contain resources'

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

My `serverless.yml` file looks like this

```
functions:
  login:
    handler: login.handler
    timeout: 30
    memorySize: 128
    description: Login and save new temp user profile
    events:
      - http: 
          path: login
          method: any
          cors: true
```

I can run `sls deploy` without any problem. But after I just add `disableLogs: true` under handler  to make it

```
functions:
  login:
    handler: login.handler
    disableLogs: true
    timeout: 30
```

running `sls deploy` will return:

```
An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - Policy statement must contain resources. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 72975262-b9ac-4729-a6d6-cd6cf90c5db0; Proxy: null).
```

Comment: Any update or solutions? I'm having the same error with serverless 3.17.0 and serverless-esbuild 1.27.1.

Comment: Seems related to this issue https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/9107